# Dimension of Solution Space of Homogeneous System

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I'm quite new to Linear Algebra.So, I hope someone would help me with this.

For linear systems with n unknowns and with matrix of coefficients
A, if the rank of A is r then following holds

> The Vector Space of Solutions of the associated Homogeneous System has
>   Dimension n − r

There is already question about it here

[Why is dimension of solution space of homogeneous equations n-r?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2498226/why-is-dimension-of-solution-space-of-homogeneous-equations-n-r)  but it doesn't provide proof to it.

Could someone point to proof of this result (Hints would be more appreciated )?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This follows from the fact that if $\ \mathbf{T}: V \to W$ is a linear transformation from finite dimensional vector spaces $V$ and $W$, then we can represent $\mathbf{T}$,  in terms of the bases of $V$ and $W$, by a matrix and the dimension formula:
$$ \mathsf{dim} V = \mathsf{dim}(ker \  \mathbf{T}) \ + \  \mathsf{dim}( Img \ \mathbf{T})  $$

Sketch of the proof: Assume $\ \mathsf{dim}V = n \ $. If $\ ( \alpha_1,\dots, \alpha_k) $ is a basis for the subspace $\ ker \mathbf{T}$, then this basis can be extended to a basis of $V$, say $( \alpha_1,\dots, \alpha_k, \beta_1, \dots, \beta_{n-k})$. If we let $$w_i = \mathbf{T}(\beta_i) \quad for  \ i = 1, \dots, n-k$$ 
and show that the set $\{w_1, \dots, w_{n-k}\}$ is linearly independent and spans the image of the transformation, then the dimension of the image is $n-k$, proving  the dimension formula.