# Proof of the solution spaces of the homogenous systems being coincident

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-calculus, homogeneous-spaces

In the very beginning, I'm going to refer to a similar post dealing with theory:[Why is dimension of solution space of homogeneous equations n-r?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2498226/why-is-dimension-of-solution-space-of-homogeneous-equations-n-r)

> Let $A,S\in M_n, n\in\mathbb N,$ where $S$ is regular.
>
> $(a)$ Prove that the solution spaces of homogeneous systems
> $AX=0\;\&\;(SA)X=0$ coincide.
>
> $(b)$ Prove that dimensions of the solution spaces of the homogeneous
> systems $AX=0\;\&\;(AS)X=0$ are equal.
>
> $(c)$ Let $\operatorname{rank}(A)<\frac{n}2$ Prove that systems $AX=0\;\&\;(AS)X=0$
> have at least $1$ non-trivial common solution.

My attempt:

$(a)$
I took the regularity of $S$ into account and saw that left multiplication by $S$ would affect neither the result in the second equation nor change the dimension (what is to be proven in $(b)$). I first thought of proving $$A,S\in M_n\;\&\;\det(S)\ne0\implies[\{A\}]=[\{SA\}]$$
and use the fact that the coefficient matrices $A\;\&\;SA$ are of the same type just like $AX\;\&\;(SA)X$. However, I wasn't sure if $\text{associativity}$ was sufficient. What I know for sure is that $X$ is either a$\text{zero-divisor}$ (depending on $\operatorname{rank}(A)=\operatorname{rank}(SA)$, which is to be proven in $(c)$) or a $\text{null-matrix}$. My notation got complicated, but I should be able to transform the matrices into canonical ones to get the basis.

$A,S\in M_n\implies X\in M_{nk}$

Let $N,P\leq M_{nk}$
$$N:=\{X_{nk}:AX=0, A\in M_n\}, P:=\{X_{nk}: (SA)X=0, A,S\in M_n\}$$
then I have to prove:
$$\begin{aligned}N=P\iff& N\leq P\;\&\; P\leq N\\\iff&[\{N\}]=[\{P\}]\\\iff& [\{N\}]\subseteq [\{P\}]\;\&\; [\{P\}]\subseteq [\{N\}]\\\iff& (\forall X'\in N) X'\in P\;\&\;(\forall X''\in P) X''\in N\end{aligned}$$
I decided to express the elements of the following matrices according to properties of the matrix product in order to prove the statement above is true for every $\text{column (row) vector}$ in the vector space-$\text{union of linear spans of}$ $\operatorname{rank}(AX)=\operatorname{rank}((SA)X)$ $\text{vectors}$.

\begin{aligned}(AX)_{im}&=\sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij}x_{jm},\ i\in\{1,\ldots,n\},m\in\{1,\ldots,k\}&\\(AS)_{ij}&=\sum_{l=1}^n a_{il}s_{lj},&\\((AS)X)_{im}&=\sum_{t=1}^n(AS)_{it}x_{tm}&\\&=\sum_{t=1}^n\left(\sum_{j=1}^na_{il}s_{lj}\right)_{it}x_{tm}\forall C=((AX)_{1m},(AX)_{2m},\ldots,(AX)_{im}),j\in\{1,\ldots,n\}\\ &C\in\bigcup_{m=1}^{m=k}[\{(((SA)X)_{1m},((SA)X)_{2m},\ldots,((SA)X)_{im})\}]\end{aligned}
And vice-versa for $D=(((SA)X)_{1m},((SA)X)_{2m},\ldots,((SA)X)_{im}),\ m\in\{1,\ldots,k\}$.
I don't think I've proven anything so far.

In part $(c)$, $\operatorname{rank}(A)\leq \left\lfloor\frac{n}2\right\rfloor,n=2k-1, k\in\Bbb N\;$ or $\;r(A)\leq \frac{n}2-1\;,n=2k,k\in\Bbb N.$
There should be, as mentioned in the answer to the linked question, more than $\frac{n}{2}\;\text{linearly independent zero-divisors}$?

Comment: (a) if $Av=0$, then $(SA)v=S0=0$. Therefore the solutions of $Ax=0$ are contained in the solutions of $(SA)x=0$. If $(SA)v=0$, then $0=S^{-1}(SA)v=(S^{-1}S)Av=Av$. Therefore the solutions of $(SA)x=0$ are also contained in the solutions of $Ax=0$.

Comment: @MoonLightSyzygy Thank you.

Comment: (b) If $Av=0$, then $S^{-1}v$ satisfies $(AS)S^{-1}v=A(SS^{-1})v=Av=0$. Therefore, $S^{-1}$ sends solutions of $Ax=0$ to solutions $S^{-1}x$ of $(AS)x=0$. Conversely, if $(AS)v=0$, then $Sv$ satisfies $A(Sv)=0$. Therefore, $S$ sends solutions of $(AS)x=0$ to solutions $Sx$ of $Ax=0$. Therefore $x\mapsto Sx$ is a (linear) bijection between the sets of solutions of $Ax=0$ and $(AS)x=0$. Therefore, these have the same dimension.

Comment: (c) If $r(A)<n/2$, then the dimension $d$ of the set $E$ of solutions of $Ax=0$ is $>n-n/2=n/2$. By (b) the set $F$ of solutions of $(AS)x=0$ also has dimension $d>n/2$. It follows that $n\geq \dim(E+F)=\dim(E)+\dim(F)-\dim(E\cap F)=2d-\dim(E\cap F)$. It follows that $\dim(E\cap F)=2d-n>0$. Therefore, the space $E\cap F$ contain vectors other than $0$.

Comment: @MoonLightSyzygy, thank you once again! I should've written this task appeared in Linear Algebra 1 exam, because, when I googled 'linear bijection' it appeared in materials for the next collegium, but I understand what you wrote, it makes sense.

Comment: For (b) you could instead show that if $v_1,v_2,...,v_k$ is a basis of the set of solutions of $(AS)x=0$, then $Sv_1,Sv_2,...,Sv_k$ is also linearly independent, are solutions of $Ax=0$ and generate the set of solutions of this system.

Comment: @MoonLightSyzygy, may I ask if you could make your comments an answer so the question isn't in the unanswered questions queue?